# Using backquote inside backquote in js

Tags: node.js

I want to use backquote inside backquote string in javascript.For example I have below code

```
var queryString = `UPDATE `order` SET status = 'open' WHERE uid = '${row.uid}'`;
```

here `order` should be quoted with backquote in order for it to work in my sql statements.

This gives invalid syntax error.

P.s I am using backquote mainly to use variables like `${var}`

Comment: What will happen if someone manages to set `row.uid` to `' OR '' = '` ? (Or `'; DROP TABLE order; --`, for that matter.)

Comment: its nodejs , how can they set it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can escape a backtick in a backtick-delimited string with a backslash...

```
var queryString = `UPDATE \`order\` SET ...
```

I'd highly recommend figuring out how to use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with whatever database you're using instead - interpolating variables directly into queries makes you vulnerable to SQL injection and other bugs, and is quite inelegant. Ideally, for a query, you should *never* have to interpolate anything into the string. (and so should never have anything like `${row.uid}` in a template literal)